# Cypress click middle button in last row

Tags: cypress

I have a multiple rows with div:

```
<div class="item">
<div... >some header and other text</div>
<div class="actions">
<button class="btn-action"><svg..></button>
<button class="btn-action"><svg..></button>
<button class="btn-action"><svg..></button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<div... >some header and other text</div>
<div class="actions">
<button class="btn-action"><svg..></button>
<button class="btn-action"><svg..></button>
<button class="btn-action"><svg..></button>
</div>
</div>
```

So the divs with class item are repeating and can be 10 or more on th epage.

I need to click the second button on the LAST row.

I tried:

```
cy.get['.item button.btn-action:nth(1)'].last().click()
```

However this is clicking the 2nd button but in the first row, not the last.

I suppose first I need to select the last div e.g.

```
cy.get['.item'].last()
```

and then somehow to select the correct button with nth(), but not sure how when I get only the last div via cy.get.

Comment: Does each row have unique text? Does each button have unique text?

Comment: text can be unique but can be the same, it is changing, we don't know what text will be there as it is user's input. Buttons doesn't have text, they have same class, just svg image differs.

Comment: It would be great if you could somehow control that data when you are trying to locate the button you want to click. Otherwise, your solution will work for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok for now I found a solution with find command, seems this is working fine:

cy.get('.item').last().find('button:nth(1)').click()

Comment: If you knew that there were only ever going to be three buttons, you could change `.find('button:nth(1)')` to `.find('button').eq(1)`. Just a personal preference, as I try not to include `nth`s and the like in my selectors. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq